# Is it possible to change Facebox's settings at runtime? How?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebox

Is it possible to access Facebox settings? For example, I'd like to do set the location of the loading image dynamically (see line 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>media/facebox/facebox.js" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    Facebox.loadingImage = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>media/facebox/loading.gif'; // <-- is this possible?
    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();
  });
</script>
```

Is this possible? How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible:

```
$('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({ 
    loading_image : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>media/facebox/loading.gif'
})
```

Comment: see also facebox google group: http://groups.google.com/group/facebox/browse_thread/thread/9f4ce9aa04e300b0